# FileNotFoundException while trying to convert contacts to Vcard

Tags: android

I m trying to convert the contacts on emulator to VCard format using the code  below

AssetFileDescriptor afd =openAssetFileDescriptor(Contacts.CONTENT_VCARD_URI ,"r")

The stack Trace says 
java.io.FileNotFoundException No file at content://com.android.contacts/contacts/as_vcard

Do we need to attach a file to the URI ? Is there some other way to convert Contacts to Vcard in Android?

Comment: I hope this answer will help you: "[Android get vCard data from Intent][1]"


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12659323/android-get-vcard-data-from-intent/12771561#12771561

Answer (score 2):

You have to iterate through the contact db and call openAssetFileDescriptor() on each one individually. The important part is that you have to use the lookup key for each contact and append it to the CONTENT_VCARD_URI using the URI.withAppendedPath() method.

Answer (score 1):

I just stumbled with this one too. Here is a way to do it. 1st let the user pick his contact or get the contactUri another way.

After you have the contactUri you lookup the lookup_key and after that you can retrieve the vcard. Here is the code I used after i got the contactUri (kind of copy paste from different functions, but should work).

```
Cursor cursor = resolver.query(contactUri, new String[] {
    Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY
}, null, null, null);
FileInputStream input = null;

try {
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        return cursor.getString(0);
    } else return;

    AssetFileDescriptor afd = context.getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(
            Uri.withAppendedPath(Contacts.CONTENT_VCARD_URI, lookupKey), "r");
    input = afd.createInputStream();

    int ch;
    StringBuffer strContent = new StringBuffer("");
    while ((ch = input.read()) != -1)
        strContent.append((char) ch);

    Log.d(TAG, strContent.toString());
} finally {
    cursor.close();
    if (input != null) {
        input.close();
    }
}
```