# Android get vCard data from Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, vcf-vcard

I use `Intent.ACTION_SEND` for receiving data in my app. How can I process sending of data type `text/x-vcard`?

When I use `intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT)`, it's throws an exception.

Comment: Can you see if this is helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599567/android-vcard-string-to-contact

Comment: No, I have read this, that article is about how to send but not how to receive.

Comment: Btw, How are you sending you VCard? That code will be helpful. You can try intent.getData() if you are using uri.

Comment: I simple add permission to receive `<data android:mimeType="text/*" />` with `intent-filter` and when click export contact select my app.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
Uri uri = (Uri) intent.getExtras().get(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
```

`uri.toString()` gave me this:

```
content://com.android.contacts/contacts/as_multi_vcard/2876r7-2A962A902A9045494F35.1957ifcf79ef7e82a0b99%3A2876r8-315551534945354F312D4F35.1957ieb4f1a6b0fcb82b9%3A2876r9-57493D3135452D3D43.1957ief585d48b64784c0%3A2876r10-4F35373D4343474959.1957if0a70009608fae23%3A2876r11-313B3531412F2D432D473135.1957i39c8fd1b6ef69e84%3A1957i51f47cecc7822f19.4035i611323cd8d55aa13%3A4035i8.4035i74aa09b30a019fa1%3A4035i2c0b359c8a47878e%3A4035i6d3c40138feef64b%3A4035i7d583f5488e47e41%3A4035ia6.4035i5%3A4035i6029e050898a86d3%3A4035i77caf53c89b4da48%3A4035i2a11745a8f3d5667%3A4035i9%3A4035i59ab32fd0fa955a9%3A4035i7391f1908a38ed1b%3A4035i6769848b08a214b0%3A4035i5a7c03c88bd1ba9e%3A4035i126427da8dfc0763%3A4035i35003ea5093abeb0%3A4035i1906758a8e16ca3a%3A4035i59a7953d883a78bf%3A4035i64249c098820452a%3A4035i48145af48ed78ebc%3A4035i2093d7568be9dff6%3A4035i469c62120db59d35.4035i388017020fbfb07e%3A4035i47e19c048aa116d7%3A239i3%3A239i2%3A239i249%3A239i248%3A239i1,
```

which is not terribly useful in that form, but there seem to be several posts on stack about getting a usable path from a URI.

To get the text from the vcard, the following seems to be working for me:

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
InputStream stream = null;
try {
    stream = cr.openInputStream(uri);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

StringBuffer fileContent = new StringBuffer("");
int ch;
try {
    while( (ch = stream.read()) != -1)
      fileContent.append((char)ch);
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
String data = new String(fileContent);
Log.i("TAG", "data: " + data);
```

The string will have carriage returns, so to see all of the text in the logcat, make sure to search for the tag (in the above code it's "TAG"), so you see all the lines (see my screenshot below).

[image: Screenshot of logcat]

Comment: Yes, I have received the same, but how can I get vCard data in TEXT formats like here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard.

Comment: Thanks, works, but you forgot `stream.close();` after stream reading.

Comment: For anyone interested, the following posts helped me figure out the answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5968896/listing-all-extras-of-an-intent
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5857148/android-intent-extra-stream
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2789276/android-get-real-path-by-uri-getpath