# Android get vCard from intent

Tags: android, android-intent, vcf-vcard

I am trying to receive vCard from `Intent`:

```
// ...

Intent intent = getIntent();
String action = intent.getAction();
String type = intent.getType();

if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {
    if ("text/plain".equals(type)) {
        handleSendText(intent);
    } else if ("text/x-vcard".equals(type)) {
        handleSendVCard(intent);
    }
}

// ...

private void handleSendVCard(Intent intent) {
    Uri uri = intent.getData();
    Log.d("vCard", uri.toString());
}
```

But get `NullPointerException`. How can I get vCard from intent?

Comment: Where exactly do you get the NPE?

Comment: This problem is already resolved. You can find solution by [this URL][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12659323/android-get-vcard-data-from-intent/12771561#12771561